# Why is wallet.dat BerkeleyDB instead of LevelDB?

Tags: wallet.dat, leveldb, datadir

Why wasn't `wallet.dat` migrated to LevelDB?

Is it because

- BerkeleyDB is better at [something]
- Backwards compatibility

Comment: Since you use the word "migrated", it seems that you are aware that LevelDB was not a very popular choice in 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BerkeleyDB support  ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability). Leveldb no ACID, I think this is the main reason using BerkeleyDB.